# auf oder an eine Bank setzen

Tags: translation, preposition

Wie übersetzt man "to sit on a bench" auf Deutsch?
[Hier](http://deutsch-als-fremdsprache-grammatik.de/DaF/praepositionen.pdf) (siehe z.B Seite 17) liest man:

> Jeder Schüler sitz **an** einer Bank (bzw. setzt sich **an** eine Bank).

Aber wenn ich nach ["sich an eine Bank setzen" in Google suche](https://www.google.ch/search?safe=active&biw=1235&bih=925&q=sich%20an%20eine%20bank%20setzen&oq=sich%20an%20eine%20bank%20setzen&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3284.3884.0.4045.5.5.0.0.0.0.166.442.0j3.3.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..2.0.0.AXRTfm9DS1E), taucht nur die Forme:

> jdn **auf** eine Bank setzen

auf.

Also ist die erste dieser zweien Möglichkeiten falsch, oder halt selten verwendet? Oder habe ich was übersehen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Du hast etwas übersehen:

Die Bank *an* der ein Schüler sitzt ist heute nur noch ein Tisch - und wenn Schüler *auf* diesem sitzen, werden sie meist ermahnt. Im Bezug auf die Namensgebung ist in der heutigen Arbeitsplatzausstattung für Schüler die eigentliche "Bank" nämlich weggefallen.

Ursprünglich saßen Schüler an/in speziellen Möbeln, die eine Kombination aus Sitzbank mit Tisch bildeten, oft mit eingebautem Tintenfass und Ablagefach unter der Tischplatte:
[image]
[Quelle](http://www.luxury-park.de/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/I/A/IA3__1_.JPG)
Die ganze Kombination heißt "Schulbank", oft im damaligen und heutigen Sprachgebrauch zu "Bank" verkürzt.

Handelt es sich bei der Bank dagegen um ein Sitzmöbel (= überbreiter Stuhl), dann sitzt man *auf* ihr.

Comment: In Kirchen gibt es auch Bänke. Setzt man sich vielleicht auch an eine bestimmte Bank in einem Biergarten?

Comment: @userunknown Kirchenbänke (auch manchmal Schulbänke, wie in der Antwort erwähnt) sind was, wo man sich *hinein* setzt, man setzt sich in der Kirche also **in** eine Bank. Und im Biergarten hängt's vom Konsum ab, da liegt man auch bisweilen drunter...

Comment: @userunknown in der Kirche setze ich mich *in* die Bank (ein Möbelstück analog zur Schulbank), im Biergarten platziere ich meinen Allerwertesten *auf* der Bank.

Answer (score -2):

Dass man **auf** einer Bank sitzt, wurde bereits erklärt. Es gibt allerdings zwei Versionen von *»Bank«*, die sich in Bedeutung und Plural unterscheiden:

> - *Sitzgelegenheit:* 1 Bank, 2 Bänke
> - *Kreditinstitut:* 1 Bank, 2 Banken

Mit diesem Plural sollte man sich nicht vertun wie etwa der Fremde, der die Frage, was er in Deutschland tue, wie folgt beantwortete:

> Ich will Bänke überfallen.

Comment: Noch sind es null Punkte, ich hoffe heute Nacht auf einen Besoffenen.

Comment: Bier is alle, sorry.